# Best way to incorporate schema into heroku pgbackups clone from production data

Tags: postgresql, heroku, backup

Sometimes to test out my apps, I use heroku pgbackups to copy my production data into my staging instance.  However, if there are tables present in staging that are not in production, loading the backup leaves them there.

I'm wondering if there's a good way to knock them out so my migrations will apply in exactly the same way I can expect them to work in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply drop and recreate the relevant schema before you restore the backup from Heroku:

```
DROP SCHEMA xyz CASCADE;
```

Be sure that it is ok to delete everything in the schema!
Not sure if a) your staging instance is on Heroku, too, and b) Heroku would allow you to do that.

Comment: This looks like a good, simple plan, albeit not as convenient as using the heroku toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily start on a blank slate by deleting all data on the target database with the `heroku pg:reset` command, prior to invoking the restore command.

Comment: Does this drop the tables? Doesn't sound like it would.